# the value in a const list literal must be constants

Tags: flutter, dart

```
SizedBox(
    width: double.infinity,
    child: RawMaterialButton(
    fillColor: Color(900), 
    elevation: 0.0,
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
)
```

> Error.
> "message": "The values in a const list literal must be constants.\nTry removing the keyword 'const' from the list literal.",
> "source": "dart", const at the start of SIZED BOX

Answer (score 3):

You are using a dynamic value i.e. double.infinity in the SizedBox properties that's why it doesnot allow const keyword with the SizedBox. Just remove the keyword and it works fine. Or put static value in the width. Like below:

```
const SizedBox(
   width: 24,
   child: RawMaterialButton(
   fillColor: Color(900),
   elevation: 0.0,
   padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0),
   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(),
)
```